# Uploading a minor new build must wait for review every time?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I just fixed a few bugs and minor things after the initial version of an application was released into the app store. I've uploaded the binary to iTunesConnect but I see nowhere to change over the build version. Is it correct that every time a new version/build(1.0.1 -> 1.0.2) is uploaded it has to go through review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Apple requires that every new build, regardless of how small, go thru the App Review processes.  If you have a bad bug and need to get a fix out there quickly, you can request an expedited review.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as an App has been already reviewed, uploading a new binary requires a new revision.

Extracted from Apple's [Replacing your App with a New Version](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1):

> You will only be able to add a new version for a new platform or a platform that has a Ready for Sale or Developer Removed from Sale version. **If a platform version has not completed the app review process—it has a status such as Prepare For Submission or Waiting For Review—you can replace the build in the existing version instead of adding a new version.**